# Log4j works for one class and doesn't work for the other class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j

I am developing a Spring MVC 3.0.4 webapp and Logger factroy doesn't work for the Controller classes other than HomeController.java. I initilize the Logger factory like:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestDataController.class);
```

and

```
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

is added for both classes

What configuration is missing?

Comment: does it initialize correctly?

Comment: Are both HomeController and RequestDataController in the same package?

Comment: @Viktor: No. They are not. And there is no error or warning.

Comment: Can you provide your slf4j properties file and full class names for HomeController and RequestDataController?

Comment: I don't have any slf4j propperties file and i did not do any configuration. T have created a Spring MVC project on STS 2.6.1. HomeController which comes default is com.yakup.deneme.HomeController,java and RequestDataController is com.yakup.data.RequestDataController.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems SLF4J is missconfigured. You use it for you own logging and that's a right choice! But Spring has [JCL](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) logging framework hardcoded. It's an abstarction layer that is typically configured with [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) implementation. Please, visit this [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?42249-Spring-with-SLF4J) where some JCL-to-SLF4J drop-in replacements described. If you want to leave both Log4J and SLF4j in your project than add proper logging preferences into log4j.properties or log4j.xml for core spring packages.

Comment: And the Tomcat was hosting to porjects at the same time. When i removed the other project everything was OK. Thanx for the help.